# how to retrieve followers from twitter and store in database in php

Tags: php

```
<?php


    session_start();
    require_once("twitter/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); 

    $username="root";
    $password = "root";
    $database="gift";
    mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);

    if ( !$db_selected ) {
        die( "Unable to select database");
    }
    $queryy = "SELECT * FROM 'twitter'";
    $resultt = mysql_query($queryy);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($resultt)) {
        $accesstoken=$row['twit_email'];
        $accesstokensecret=$row['password'];

        }
               $cursor = -1;
                    $followers = array();

              do {
            $json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?cursor=' . $cursor);
            $accounts = json_decode($json);
            foreach ($accounts->users as $account)
                $followers[$account->id_str] = $account->screen_name;

            $cursor = $accounts->next_cursor;

        } while ($cursor > 0);

        // Now save in the database
        foreach($followers as $key => $value) {

            $res = $this-> $database->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `twit_contacts` WHERE twitID = :id');
            $res->execute(array('id' => $key));
            $rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            if (!$rows[0])
                $this->$database->prepare('INSERT INTO `twit_contacts` SET twitID = :id, contactName = :name, dateContactFrom = NOW()')
                        ->execute(array(':id' => $key, ':name' => $value));
            else
                $this->$database->prepare('UPDATE `twit_contacts` SET contactName = :name, dateContactFrom = NOW() WHERE twitID = :id')
                        ->execute(array(':id' => $key, ':name' => $value));
        }









    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'twit_contacts'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $oldFollowers = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $oldFollowers[$row->contactID] = array('screen_name'=>$row->screen_name, 'contactName'=>$row->username);
        echo $oldFollowers['screen_name'];
    }


    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Please add some description in question, what error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

screen name, 'username'=>name)
    $oldFollowers = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $oldFollowers[$row->twitID] = array('screen_name'=>$row->screen_name, 'contactName'=>$row->contactName);
    }
    // now, set up the details needed to connect using the twitterouth library
    // these details will be on your application page at https://dev.twitter.com/apps
    // (you'll need to create an app if you have not already done this)
    $consumerkey = '';
    $consumersecret = '';
    $accesstoken = $_SESSION['request_token'];
    $accesstokensecret = $_SESSION['request_token_secret'];

    function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
      $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
      return $connection;
    }

    // make the connection
    $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

    // retrieve the list of followers - if you have more than 100 followers, adjust the count number accordingly
    // the maximum figure for count is 200 - if you have more than 200 followers, you'll need to use cursors
    // to download multiple pages of results - this is beyond the scope of this script, but information
    // can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring
    $sql = "SELECT screen_name FROM twitter where myID ='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$screen=$row['screen_name'];
echo $screen;

    $result = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?screen_name=$screen&count=100");
    // create an array to store the retrieved followers
    $newFollowers = array();

    foreach ($result->users as $follower) {
    echo 'hhhhhhhhh';
        $id = $follower->id;
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($follower->name);
        echo $name;

        $screen_name = mysql_real_escape_string($follower->screen_name);
        echo $screen_name ;
        $newFollowers[$id] = array('screen_name'=>$screen_name, 'contactName'=>$name);
    }

    // one by one, check the existing followers array members to see if they exist in the retrieved followers array
    // if they do not, then that user is no longer following you, so output a message
    foreach (array_keys($oldFollowers) as $oldFollower) {
        if (is_null($newFollowers[$oldFollower])) { //if old follower is no longer following
            echo $oldFollowers[$oldFollower]['screen_name']." (".$oldFollowers[$oldFollower]['contactName'].") is no longer following you.\n";
        }
    }
    //  clear the old table
    $query = "TRUNCATE `twit_contacts`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //  build the new table using the retrieved followers
    foreach (array_keys($newFollowers) as $newFollower) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `twit_contacts` VALUES ('".$newFollower."', '".$newFollowers[$newFollower]['contactName']."', '".$newFollowers[$newFollower]['screen_name']."')";

        $result = mysql_query($query);

    }   

    mysql_close();
?>